# Java Sound call hogging too much CPU after upgrading from JRE 7u51 to JRE 7u55

Tags: java, multithreading, javax.sound.sampled

Using jstack to profile the most CPU intensive thread, I was able to find out that the AudioSystem.getMixer() call was hogging all my CPU. I haven't changed anything in the code, only the version of java (from 7u51 to 7u55). This call is in a tight loop in a thread that with pauses lasting only 20ms. Any idea on how I can begin to find a solution to this?

I am running Ubuntu 14.04 x86_64 and JRE 7u55 64 bit. This happens to all newer versions of java.

```
"MonitorThread" prio=10 tid=0x00007f57bc409000 nid=0x2e36 runnable [0x00007f5778f85000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
at com.sun.media.sound.DirectAudioDeviceProvider.nGetNumDevices(Native Method)
at com.sun.media.sound.DirectAudioDeviceProvider.init(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.media.sound.DirectAudioDeviceProvider.<init>(Unknown Source)
- locked <0x00000000f07721b0> (a java.lang.Class for com.sun.media.sound.DirectAudioDeviceProvider)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor7.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Service$LazyIterator.next(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.media.sound.JSSecurityManager.getProviders(Unknown Source)
- locked <0x00000000f05556e0> (a java.lang.Class for com.sun.media.sound.JSSecurityManager)
at com.sun.media.sound.JDK13Services.getProviders(Unknown Source)
at javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem.getProviders(Unknown Source)
at javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem.getMixerProviders(Unknown Source)
at javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem.getMixer(Unknown Source)
at Client$MonitorAllAudio.run(Client.java:8941)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: can you post your sample code? My money is on your "tight loop in a thread with pauses lasting only 20ms" being the culprit... and it's possible it's been the issue all along but only a newer JVM exposed the problem. Have you tried this using Java 8? Same issue? Also, are you running this on your Ubuntu system only, or have you tried other OS's/systems? It's possible there is a bug in PulseAudio or whatever audio framework you are using in the OS.